# Plotly reference documentation as plain HTML/Markdown files?

Tags: html, markdown, plotly, documentation, converters

For the Python charting library [Plotly](https://plot.ly/) the [reference documentation](https://plot.ly/python/reference/) is pretty slow to navigate. Standalone files would be sooo much easier!

Is there a way to download the reference documentation as HTML/Markdown files?

Comment: Why not just save the webpage, I tried it and it seems to navigate as usual.

Comment: Yep, sort of works. Not very neat, but better than nothing. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!